# Settings to move to end of line using tmux

Tags: tmux

Annoying question to have to ask!  In bash (or anywhere.. like when editing this question) I can do `CTRL + left|right` to move left left or right to different bits of whitespace.  With `tmux` running.. this does work.. it doesn't do anything.  How do you do the same thing but with `tmux`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. bash, respectively readline, has an idea of what you typed and can therefore jump as many characters until the next "word boundary". tmux does not have this information. Also, in tmux and the ANSI code space, I would interpret "end of line" in fact as \r\e[xB (with *x* being the size of the window), though that did not match up with your expectation.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by binding C-Left and C-Right to "send-keys M-b" and "send-keys M-f" in your ~/.tmux.conf file like this:

```
bind-key -n C-Left send-keys M-b
bind-key -n C-Right send-keys M-f
```